# Install Windows 10 Creators Update on iMac11,2 without first installing Windows 8

Tags: macos, bootcamp, imac, windows

Having trouble installing Windows 10 version 1703 on the old iMac (`iMac11,2  MC509LL/A`) running macOS 10.12.5.

The official page said it didn't support Windows 10, but according to my experience as long as it supports Windows 8, it supports Windows 10, too. I'm trying to setup W10 directly without first setting up W8 and then upgrading. Tutorials of modifying Boot Camp failed because `codesign` keeps on telling me "bundle format unrecognized".

Is there a way to setup Windows 10 Creators Update directly on this iMac?

Answer (score 1):

There's a difference between the Microsoft & Apple definitions of "support".

If Apple says it's unsupported that means there are no Windows 10 drivers for your hardware.

Whether that is a minor inconvenience or a catastrophic fail you'd have to try it to see.

The difference in definition isn't only an Apple/MS distinction... MS allowed people on regular Windows PCs to update to WIn10 even though Intel themselves weren't making drivers available for their hardware.
At least Apple are telling you up front you will have no proper hardware support.

Comment: Most Windows 8 drivers can be forced onto Windows 10, whereas the driver for the graphics card can be acquired from AMD, so there should be no problem, I think.

Comment: even AMD don't provide Win10 drivers for the HD 4xxx series, they legacied it in 2013. You might get so far using Win8 drivers, but that only reinforces my answer... minor or catastrophic, only one way to find out

Comment: Fortunately, it's not any HD 4xxx, but HD 5670 instead :) It's a Mid-2010 iMac, as noted above.

Comment: Then it's still a legacy product, but they did one driver that kind of works for Win10 [avoid the Crimson beta] I was basing my info on http://www.everymac.com/ultimate-mac-lookup/?search_keywords=iMac11,2